# WeakEventManager for Windows Store Apps

Tags: events, garbage-collection, windows-store-apps, weak-references

I cannot find `WeakEventManager` for Windows Store Apps and wonder what should be used instead in order to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WeakReference` and relay events if the target is alive. Check the Kona Guidance [here](http://konaguidance.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/cb2b257e240e7700c55b0c5860dc24155103a5eb#PubSubEvents/DelegateReference.cs).